# A better way to do replacement tags in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, templating

I need a better way to do this:

```
Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(textMessage.Trim(), "{birthday}", person.Birthday, RegexOptions.None), "{phone}", person.MobilePhone, RegexOptions.None), "{email}", person.Email, RegexOptions.None), "{lastname}", person.LastName, RegexOptions.None), "{firstname}", person.FirstName, RegexOptions.None)
```

Comment: string.Format()? a string's Replace() method? more detail?

Comment: Why are you going to all the trouble of using Regex.Replace when your "regular expression" is just a literal string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
textMessage.Trim()
    .Replace("{birthday}",person.Birthday)
    .Replace("{phone}",person.Phone)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IDictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
replacements.Add("{birthday}", person.Birthday);
replacements.Add("{phone}", person.MobilePhone);
...

foreach (string s in replacements.Keys) {
    Regex.Replace(textMessage, s, replacements[s], RegexOptions.None);
}
```

Comment: You might as well be using String's own `Replace` method, as others have observed.  And if you must use the Regex version, don't bother specifying `RegexOptions.None`.  That's the same as not specifying any options, making it pure clutter.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to match on say, `{word}` and then use the [Replace overload that takes a MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx).

Then it's easy to have a dictionary (or switch or whatever) provide the replacement input (for the given "word").

There are additional advantages such as better run-time characteristics (`O(n)` vs `O(k*n)`), scales nicely/allows separation of replacement data, and isn't affected if one of the replacements contains `{}` stuff.

Happy coding.

---

I dug this out of an old project. It looks like this even "understands" formatting. YMMV.

```
/// <summary>
/// Like string.Format but takes "{named}" identifiers with a Dictionary
/// of replacement values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="format"></param>
/// <param name="replaces"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Format(string format, IDictionary<string,object> replaces) {
    if (format == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("format");
    if (replaces == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("replaces");
    return Regex.Replace(format, @"{(?<key>\w+)(?:[:](?<keyFormat>[^}]+))?}", (match) => {
        Object value;
        var key = match.Groups["key"].Value;
        var keyFormat = match.Groups["keyFormat"].Value;
        if (replaces.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyFormat)) {
                return "" + value;
            } else {
                // format if applicable
                return string.Format("{0:" + keyFormat + "}", value);
            }
        } else {
            // don't replace not-found
            return match.Value;
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, in a more trivial manner (extracted from above, YMMV x2):

```
var person = GetPerson(); // I love closures
var res = Regex.Replace(input, @"{(?<key>\w+)}", (match) => {
    switch (match.Groups["key"].Value) {
        case "birthday": return person.Birthday;
        // ....
        default: return "";
    }
});
```